# Is it possible to scroll jQuery UI accordion h3 overflow in a resizable div?

Tags: jquery-ui, scroll, overflow

I'm attempting to use the accordion for a very long list of records, where the accordion is wrapped in a resizable div that is given a fixed amount of space on the page and you would scroll to find the h3's that are too high or too low to see. The problem that I'm having is that the headers always force the size of their div, so the "overflow: scroll" is essentially ignored as the h3's spill out of the explicitly sized parent.

We are using jQuery 1.6.2, and UI 1.8.16

[image: h3s overflowing]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/GVFsn/

Comment: So I left out something important... and just fixed that. The problem starts when I try to resize the containing div; then the h3's ignore the container size.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to have the resizer, and it displays the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

try applying style="clear:both" to the parent, that should work.

The accordion is floated content, and the browser does not know where it ends.

Either that or steal the .clearfix class from FaceBook